# reading from file and writing array to file - C#

Tags: c#, file

Is there any way to add a string array to file without using loop? I tried doing that with StreamWriter (writer) after spliting the string to cells in array. I seek for a way to avoid the for loop and the close() method.

Thanks!

```
if (data[0] != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        this.writer.Write(this.data[i] + "+++", true);
    }
}
this.writer.Write("\n", true);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try `File.WriteAllLines(string path, string[] lines);`

Comment: I'm curious why you really don't want to use an array.  What are you trying to do?  What is your overall goal?  If you want to use a collection, at some point, some code will loop over it

Comment: I'm good with arrays. I'm trying to find more efficiant way to do it without StreamWriter.

Comment: What makes something _"efficient"_ in your view?  I haven't looked at the source, but I'm guessing that `File.WriteAllLines` probably opens a stream writer, loops over the collection and then flushes and closes things off under the covers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to write like this, but you can try:

```
var stringToSave = string.Join("+++", data);
File.WriteAllText(stringToSave);
```

But of course there is a loop somewhere in string.Join() here. I would also like to ask you, are you sure you don't want to use:

```
File.WriteAllLines(data);
```

?
This will write every string of your collection to a seperate line...